# How to get variables from separate fragments using the same class

Tags: android, fragment

In my Android app, I have an activity with 4 fragments. All the fragments have the same exact fields, so they are all inflated from the same xml file and have the same java class.
However, I need to get the data stored in each of them because the user will be entering things in each one. So how would I be able to get the data if they all have the same class?

activity_success.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cont"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/export_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/export"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/continue_button"
    />


<fragment android:name="org.bah.bu.SuccessFragment"
    android:id="@+id/red1_success"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/continue_button"

    />

<fragment android:name="org.bah.bu.SuccessFragment"
    android:id="@+id/red2_success"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/red1_success"
    />
```

fragment_success.xml

```
<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/far"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/far"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/lifted"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lifted"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I used the `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);` method to create 4 references to the fragments and used an `updateVals()` method which stores the data from the views in the fragment in variables in the java class.

Answer (score 1):

Write a `getData()` method in the Fragment class (such that it returns the relevant information) or simply use standard getters for whatever data fields you need.  Then, in your enclosing activity, call each of the Fragment instances' `getData()` method.  Each instance will return the data it contains unique to that instance.

The important thing is that regardless of the fact that the Fragments share the same class definition, instances of them will (or can) contain different data.  Talking to the instances and not the class is the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I already had that, but I was just missing `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);`